# Weird output from df on Solaris 9

Tags: unix, solaris, disk-space-utilization

I just ran `df -h` on a Solaris 9 machine and got a a very weird output, something I have never seen before.

```
/proc                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
```

Output from `df`:

```
/proc              (/proc             ):       0 blocks    29886 files
/etc/mnttab        (mnttab            ):       0 blocks        0 files
/dev/fd            (fd                ):       0 blocks        0 files
```

Included output from `truss`:

```
statvfs64("/proc", 0xFFBFFAC8)                  = 0
/proc                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
write(1, " / p r o c              ".., 58)      = 58
statvfs64("/etc/mnttab", 0xFFBFFAC8)            = 0
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
write(1, " m n t t a b            ".., 64)      = 64
statvfs64("/dev/fd", 0xFFBFFAC8)                = 0
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
write(1, " f d                    ".., 60)      = 60
```

Does anyone know what might have caused this? And what why it's displaying this?

Thanks in advance,

Anders

Comment: Want to truss / strace it?  Does regular `df` work (not sure why you made a point of including `-h`)? My first guess is that there's some permissions problem preventing you from querying the disks for free space.

Comment: @medina, Included the output from `df`, and no, using the root account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's your / filesystem? Is this *all* output from df?
What does mount say? And "who -r" (shows runlevel), and format?
How is your vfstab?

The zero's are not that weird:

```
# df | egrep "proc|mnttab|fd"
/proc              (/proc             ):       0 blocks    15767 files
/etc/mnttab        (mnttab            ):       0 blocks        0 files
/dev/fd            (fd                ):       0 blocks        0 files
```

It seems like you're mising your disk(s). Where do you boot from?

Comment: The output you see is not weird but simply standard with Solaris. No need to fiddle with vfstab to get it.

Comment: @jillagre, Would you mind explaining that? (I'm a native Linux user, not a Solaris user)

Comment: @Anders, all of those are mountpoints for virtual filesystems. /proc is similar to Linux. mnttab is a virtual file containing mounted filesystem data, and fd is a virtual directory presenting file descriptors as files. The kernel drivers for these virtual filesystems don't return anything meaningful for the number of free blocks or files.

Comment: To add to Kenster's comment - the "files" live in the kernel. And the display is expected and completely normal because there is no file metadata, like you find in a ufs directory, to report against.
cat /etc/mnttab to see what these kernel filesystems are called.  @Oscar: And no, Anders is missing no disks based on that display.

Comment: @Kenster @jim mcnamara Thanks to both for the clarification.